# How can my website receive email from a mobile phone?

Tags: php, email, sms

I want to receive emails from mobile phone and display it on my website implemented PHP.

My site is a free messaging system that sends messages to mobile phones using [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) API

I want to display  messages from cell phones on my website. Is there any API available ?

Comment: You want to capture SMSs that are in to reply to SMSs you send?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any APIs to do this task. What you need is to setup mail server on your server to be able to receive emails. It's nothing difficult in sms to emails. It's absolutely identical to regular emails. So you should setup your mail server to call your receiver script which will process the email, insert into your database etc. Take a look at exim or qmail.

How it will work:

- your website sends email to, lets say, `91700000001@vtext.com` from `user@yourwebsite.com`
- `91700000001` replies to `user@yourwebsite.com` that goes to your mail server
- you have filter on your mail server to check, for example, if emails came from carriers domain (vtext.com, att.com etc), and hit your receiver script
- the receiver scripts gets an email, parse it, inserts into the database
- your display the data from the db on your website

Answer (score 0):

Email from mobile? Do you meant text (sms)? Every mobile phone can receive email if they have internet connection. Your question is not very clear, can you rewrite your question to understand very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

## SMS GupShup

GupShup Apps platform will allow you to create sms applications that will allow your website to interact with your system.

Check out the [FAQ](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/apps/devDashboard/faq.php) first to see if it meets your requirement.

Then check the [requirements](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/apps/devDashboard/appPlatform.php) for creating your application.

You can find the list of [APIs](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/apps/devDashboard/api.php#) here.

[Sample Code](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/apps/devDashboard/appPlatform.php#) (click on Quote App in PHP  on extreme left.)